# redirect all directory URLs except one to an external URL using .htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to redirect the following:

http://olddomain.com/products/* ---> http://shop.newdomain.com/

Except for http://olddomain.com/products/certain-category

So far I can redirect them all:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /products(.*) http://shop.newdomain.com/
```

I just need to stop redirecting 'certain-category'??

Something like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond /products(.*) !^/(certain-category)/
RewriteRule (.*) http://shop.newdomain.com/ [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Although this is redirecting the whole site to http://shop.newdomain.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this negative lookahead based rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^products/(?!certain-category).*$ http://shop.newdomain.com/ [NC,L,R=301]
```

`(?!certain-category)` is a negative lookahead that will fail the match if `certain-category` comes right after `/products/` in URL.

**Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this.**